# Can we use a custom non-x.509 cert for TLS?

Tags: tls, x.509

I know TLS normally uses a x.509 certificate. But is it possible to use a non-x.509 cert to do TLS if both the server and client understand the format of that certificates?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

The [server_certificate_type and client_certificate_type  extensions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7250) may be used to negotiate the usage of alternative certificate types. See the [TLS Certificate Type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml#tls-extensiontype-values-3) for possible values. Values in the range 224-255 are reserved for private use as per [RFC7250](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7250).